# asp.net mvc. 3-step anonymous sign-up form: How to properly Create/Edit the record between steps

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

First-time poster, long-time admirer!  :-)  Coming from ASP.NET WebForms world and building my first MVC web app.  Over the past month or so, I've watched a lot of videos and read a lot about MVC, EF Code-First, patterns, strategies, etc. Exciting!

Building an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application, which is to be a fairly simple, 3-step sign-up form on an anonymous portion of the web site.  An [anonymous] user fills out "step 1," clicks "next," and data gets recorded into a database between steps (which is desired even if the user quits before finishing step 3).

So my approach so far is to build a single "Signup" controller with 3 controller actions for the 3 steps (along with their own ViewModels containing only the needed fields for each step):

- Site/Signup/Step1 (creates a new record in DB and fills out some fields)
- Site/Signup/Step2 (edits the record created in Step1 and fills out some other fields)
- Site/Signup/Step3 (edits the record created in Step1 and fills out some other fields)

**My question is, how do I best persist a unique identifier for the newly-created record from Step1 over to steps 2 and 3, safely, securely, conveniently?**

There is an auto-identity integer SignupID, but that is not safe-enough to pass via querystring (.../Step2?id=xxx), as anyone could just type a different number and overwrite data in the database.

Some thoughts I've had so far:

1. Option: Generate a longer random number or alphanumeric code and store in DB, and use it as a URL parameter.  Maybe even GUID without hyphens or something like that.
2. Option: Persist the identifier (auto-increment ID or the longer alphanumeric code) someplace other than the querystring. Maybe Session?  TempData?
3. Option: Some combination of the two above, but with added crypto hashing or something, to ensure that the ID only works for some small period of time (say, an hour, or something).

I don't want to make this overly complex for a very small application with small number of users/sign-ups.  Just need to make it not stupidly "inviting" for poking around, considering the form needs to be filled out by anonymous users.

I'd appreciate some thoughts from the community.  Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use `@Html.HiddenFor()`, this will persist value in your form only, and whenever you post your form it will posted to your action method.

Comment: @MokshShah, A hidden field on its own can be easily tampered with (using Firebug for example)

Comment: One technique is to hash the newly created `SignupID` (say `SignupHash`). For steps 2 & 3, include hidden fields for both the `SignupID` and `SignupHash` in the form. When posted, run `SignupID` through the same hashing algorithm and if it matches the value of the posted `SignupHash`, all's good. You could even use a value from the first form as a salt.

Comment: If I use a hash, then I could just use the querystring method.  It'd be a little more visible, but not really problematic, right?